# Xamarin Mono ClientWebSocket implementation doesn't work for secure sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, mono

I'm having issues implementing a secure web socket client on Osx.
I am using ClientWebSocket from System.Net.WebSockets. Here is some test code:

```
    static async Task RunLoop()
    {
        ClientWebSocket ws = new ClientWebSocket();
        await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://echo.websocket.org"), CancellationToken.None);

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter message:");
            var msg = Console.ReadLine();
            if (msg == "quit")
            {
                break;
            }

            var b = new ArraySegment<byte>(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg));
            await ws.SendAsync(b, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

            byte[] bb = new byte[2048];
            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(bb);

            var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);

            switch (result.MessageType)
            {
                case WebSocketMessageType.Text:
                    Console.WriteLine(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array));
                    break;
                case WebSocketMessageType.Close:
                    await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", CancellationToken.None);
                    break;
            }

        } while (true);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = RunLoop();
        task.Wait();
    }
```

Every time I received this exception when ReceiveAsync is called.

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
```

Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

```
    at System.Net.WebConnection.Read (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x0001f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:1038 
  at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket+<ReceiveAsync>c__AnonStorey5.<>m__0 () [0x0017c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net.WebSockets/ClientWebSocket.cs:259 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00012] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
      at Test.MainClass+<RunLoop>c__async2.MoveNext () [0x001c0] in Program.cs:81
```

It looks like the socket is somehow getting disposed but I have no idea why and where. The same code works fine for non secure websockets ("ws://echo.websocket.org").

Tried also WebSocket.Portable implementation but had almost the same issues. For non secure websockets it worked fine but for secure websockets the OnMessage event was never called.
    https://github.com/NVentimiglia/WebSocket.Portable

Comment: The same code works fine on windows for wss.

Comment: After a request there is an alert on server side
`Frame 9852: 103 bytes on wire (824 bits), 103 bytes captured (824 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: Solarfla_07:de:fc (00:0f:53:07:de:fc), Dst: Apple_aa:05:d8 (68:5b:35:aa:05:d8)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 54.77.29.155, Dst: 10.40.131.187
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 443, Dst Port: 52146, Seq: 5121, Ack: 1038, Len: 37
Secure Sockets Layer
    TLSv1 Record Layer: Encrypted Alert
        Content Type: Alert (21)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 32
        Alert Message: Encrypted Alert`

Comment: Did you manage to find a workaround for your issue? I am having a similar issue, I can only connect using the non secure protocol and I am not sure what WebSocket infrastructure to choose for my Xamarin apps.

Comment: Hi any update on this

Answer (score 0):

I found an workaround for this issue. I used [SocketRocker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Square.SocketRocket/) which is an Objective C implementation. Square.SocketRocket is a Xamarin wrapper for the native Objective C library.
On [GitHub](https://github.com/mattleibow/square-bindings) you will find also some examples in the sample directory.